# change discriminator value at runtime?

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I'm working with a hierachy object model with a jpa entity persistance support.

Here the classes model:

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "users")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(...
})
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "apType", discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 255)
//@DiscriminatorValue("user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    protected PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new 
    PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "apType")
    private String apType;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public UsuariDeClaus() {
        this.setApType("user");

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Long oldId = this.id;
        this.id = id;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("id", oldId, id);
    }

    public String getApType() {
        return apType;
    }

    public void setApType(String apType) {
        this.apType = apType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        String oldName = this.name;
        this.name = name;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("name", oldName, name);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener 
    listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}


ApplicationUser class :

@Entity
@Table(name = "applicationuser", catalog = "usuweb793")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(...    
})

public class ApplicationUser extends Users{


    @Basic(optional = false)

    @Column(name = "nickname", unique=true)
    private String nickname;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public ApplicationUser() {
        super.setApType("ApplicationUser");
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        String oldPassword = this.password;
        this.password = password;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("password", oldPassword, password);
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        String oldNickname = this.nickname;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("nickname", oldNickname, nickname);
    }

}

and administratorUser class:

@Entity
@Table(name = "administratoruser", catalog = "usuweb793")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(...})

public class AdministratorUser extends AplicationUser{

    public AdministratorUser() {
        super.setApType("administratoruser");
    }

}
```

The entity manager creates on mysql database 4 tables:
sequence, user, aplicationuser and administratoruser.

user table:

- id     name    aptype
- 1      aaa     user
- 2      bbb     aplicationuser
- 3      ccc     administratoruser

aplicationuser table:

- id    nickname    password
- 2     bbbxxxx     bbbyyyyy
- 3     cccxxxx     cccyyyyy

administratoruser table:

- id
- 3

Is possible to change the user priviligies without remove an object and create a new one ?
(i would like the id not to change)
Something like:

User user = em.find(1);
New AplicattionUser(user);

user table:

- id     name    aptype
- 1      aaa     aplicationuser
- 2      bbb     aplicationuser
- 3      ccc     administratoruser

aplicationuser table:

- id    nickname    password
- 1     aaaxxx      aaayyyyy
- 2     bbbxxxx     bbbyyyyy
- 3     cccxxxx     cccyyyyy

administratoruser table:

- id
- 3

Comment: so as if you want to down cast the `User` to  `AplicationUser` ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: model.User cannot be cast to model.AplicationUser

Comment: yes .. exactly  :)

Comment: should I remove and create a new object ? Is the best option ?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand and from my POV, if `Application` and `Administrator` are just roles for `User`that you can switch between .... remove the inheretence, make a `User` entity and `Role` entity -with a corresponding table and join between the two entities with the appropriate join -`OneToOne` or `OneToMany` according to to your business case- ..... If you can't change the database/the code ... there is a "dirty" solution (and "dirty" again) that you might try ... make a native bulk update statement to make the change you need but be aware of the following :

1- I am nit sure if it will work, you need to try it

2- You must be sure that the entity is not managed by any persistence context at the time of running

3- You are responsible for refreshing the entity / persistence context/ cache after the update

Comment: The first solution is the one that I am now evaluating, but I lose the benefits of defining a hereditary class model.

Comment: One of the common mistakes made by object-oriented developers is that they get converted to the principle
of reuse, but carry it too far. It is too easy to get caught up in the quest for reuse and create complex inheritance
hierarchies all for the sake of sharing a few methods. These kinds of multi-level hierarchies will often lead to pain and
hardship down the road as the application becomes difficult to debug and a challenge to maintain...Large
hierarchies can often lead to significant performance reduction, and it may be that the cost of code reuse is higher
than you might want to pay

Comment: welcome any time ... if you think the answer is correct you can gracefully accept it as the correct answer